# How to add custom new test to a page in opencart 2.0.3.1 with journal 2 theme

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to add custom text to product listings (category, manufacturer, search etc)

I add all bellow for example in search.

in catalog/controller/product/search.php inside index() function and after $this->load->language('product/search'); line

```
$data['text_mystock'] = $this->language->get('text_mystock');
```

catalog/language/english/product/search.php

```
$_['text_mystock']      = 'Arriving ';
```

catalog/view/theme/journal2/template/product/search.tpl

```
<div class="p-brand" style="font-size:small;"><b style="color:red"><?php echo $text_mystock; ?></b></div>
```

Unfortunately I cannot display 'Arriving'. Where am I wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using a Journal theme, keep in mind that they do not use the default OC files. I mean  a lot OC of files are replaced by journal theme files. This is very bad because the OC is corrupted...

In your case you should add line: `$data['text_mystock'] = $this->language->get('text_mystock');`

to this file: `catalog/controller/journal2/search.php`
I hope it should solve your issue.